# Product of $H^\alpha$ function and $L^p$ function

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be closed unit disk of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $p\in(1,\infty)$ s.t. $\alpha-\beta=\frac{n}{p}$ and $\alpha<0$.

Then, when can we say that for $f\in H^\alpha(\Omega)$ and $g\in L^p(\Omega)$, $fg\in H^\beta(\Omega)$?

(I have shown the result when $p=2$ (and obviously $p=1$) and $\Omega=\mathbb{T}^n$ by basic calculation(using Fourier coefficients), but it does not seem to be generalizable.)

Comment: @ViktorGlombik : (1) It is not hw. I wrote this because encountered this problem while thinking about some regularity theory on pde(by perturbation...a bit dirty to write it here,though). (2) I have shown the result when $p=2$ and $\Omega$ is torus by basic calculation, but it does not seem to be generalizable. (3) Yes, I know Sobolev embedding. Even if you need something you think I won't know, just write it then I will search for that.

Comment: One difficulty is that $\alpha,\beta$ are negative. While we fortunately have $H$ instead of $W$, most Sobolev product theories work for nonnegative order as far as I know(but I don't know that much, though)